# How to bring back the Google Now card?

Tags: google-now

I've accidentally swiped off the Google Now calendar card on my Nexus 4 with Google Now launcher, and I missed the "undo" button. How to bring it back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do either:

- Go to the Google Now > Menu > Refresh, or
- You could try clearing the cache for Google search.

Hope that helps.